# Org-mode : Custom agenda command TODO state change log without repeating same TODO

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use 'note and timestamp' on 'DONE' state change. In my custom agenda command I define that I want to see the state change log. But it appears that I still see the original repeating TODO. I would like to only see the state change log.

I have tried two different configurations. The first does not provide me the state change, the second provides the state change log but also repeats.

Any ideas how to trim the agenda to show only the state change log?

---

TODO entry in 'company.org':

```
* Agenda
** TODO Acronis : Backup Check                                                                                                    :DAILY:
SCHEDULED: 
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2012-10-25 Thu 10:31] \\
  Reverted 'proud' back to central storage. Asked about RAM upgrade. Scheduled for Monday.
:END:
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2012-10-25 Thu 10:31]
:END:
```

---

TODO state change sequence:

```
;; '!' (for a timestamp) or '@' (for a note with timestamp)
(setq org-todo-keywords
       '((sequence "TODO(t)" "PROJ(p)" "APPT(a)" "|" "DONE(d@)")))
```

Custom agenda command:

```
("c" agenda "Company 60"
     (
      (org-agenda-files '("~/shoebox/read/org/company.org"))
      (org-agenda-ndays 60)
      (org-deadline-warning-days 7)
      (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(time-up todo-state-up priority-down))
      (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
      (org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all nil)
      (org-agenda-show-log t)
      (org-agenda-log-mode-items '(state))
      (org-agenda-show-all-dates nil) ;; only show days with something
      (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp ":DAILY:"))
      ))
```

Produces:

```
60 days-agenda (W43-W51):
Thursday   25 October 2012
  company:    10:00...... Scheduled:  TODO Acronis : Backup Check        :DAILY:
```

Where as:

```
    ("c" "Company 60"
     ((agenda ""))
     (
      (org-agenda-files '("~/shoebox/read/org/company.org"))
      (org-agenda-ndays 60)
      (org-deadline-warning-days 7)
      (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(time-up todo-state-up priority-down))
      (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
      (org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all nil)
      (org-agenda-show-log t)
      (org-agenda-log-mode-items '(state))
      (org-agenda-show-all-dates nil) ;; only show days with something
      (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp ":DAILY:"))
      ))
```

Produces:

```
60 days-agenda (W43-W51):
Thursday   25 October 2012
  Company:    10:00...... Scheduled:  TODO Acronis : Backup Check        :DAILY:
  Company:    10:31...... State:     (DONE) TODO Acronis : Backup Check - Reverted 'proud' back to central storage. Asked about RAM upgrade. Scheduled for Monday. :DAILY:
```

Comment: This removes any DONE items except State changes: `(org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)`